# Multiple eigenvectors for an eigenvalue and how to know

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    4 & 4 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} $$

This matrix has characteristic equation $- \lambda ^3 + 6 \lambda ^2 - 12 \lambda + 8$, which gives us the eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$. However, this eigenvalue has two eigenvectors, namely $(1,-2,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

How would you mathematically be able to know how many eigenvectors are associated with a single eigenvector? Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a Null Space?

Comment: Find all solutions to $(A-2I)v=0$.

Comment: To clarify, any eigenvalue has _infinitely_ many eigenvectors. What you are asking about is the maximum number of  _linearly independent_ eigenvectors it can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of linearly independent eigenvectors that are associated with an eigenvalue, is called the *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue. It can be found by solving the system $$\dim \ker(λΙ-Α)$$ 
In your case $λ=2$. To avoid confusion, the *algebraic multiplicity* of the eigenvalue is the number of times that this eigenvalue is a root of the characteristic polynomial. In your case $$p_A(λ)=-(λ-2)^3$$ so the algebraic multiplicity is equal to $3$. It is true that the geometric multiplicity is less or equal to the algebraic multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes let $v=(x,y,z)^T$ an eigenvector for the given matrix $A$ associated to $2$ then we have
$$Av=2v$$
and if we solve the system of equations we find that $v$ is a linear combination of the two vectors given in your question.